# Return multiple Text File lines between 2 specific locations with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a backup text file I need to sort out into usable information in excel. I know what the text I'm looking for is, but where it is in the text file will vary. I know how to get the file open and how to copy the whole thing, but since the data copied will be different lengths, I need it sorted into columns for other formulas to look at.

1. "/Job" and all lines until "/Pulse" to B1-B8
2. "//INST" to "NOP" to B9 (although I can make this its own column if need be)
3. all lines starting with C0 to column L
4. all lines starting with EC0 to column S
5. all lines following "*_Start" until EOF to column W

I can figure out how to search for specific single lines, but including lines under it UNTIL a certain point is proving over my head.

This is the code I've been using to get whole files from user-selected folders:

```
Dim myFile As String, textline As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("c1").Value
    Dim i As Long
        Open myFile For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            i = i + 1
            Line Input #1, textline
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp IO").Range("F" & i).Value = textline
        Loop
        Close #1
```

The backup file will look like this (I've changed values so I'm not uploading anything identifyable)

```
/JOB
//NAME 1210
//POS
///NPOS 74,0,74,0,0,0
///TOOL 0
///POSTYPE PULSE
///PULSE
C00000=65298,-31463,-18169,-24773,-119176,56781
C00001=65298,-31463,-18169,-24773,-119176,56781
C00002=65298,-45193,-17067,0,-119176,0
C00003=17144,11040,29421,-1614,-103932,438
C00004=18413,40212,49835,-5253,-77713,5101
C00005=20415,59082,68960,-2441,-91039,4411
C00006=20826,60074,63714,-1626,-91500,4377
EC00000=0,0
EC00001=0,0
EC00002=0,0
EC00003=0,0
EC00004=0,0
EC00005=0,0
EC00006=0,0
//INST
///DATE 2022/03/14 12:06
///COMM Name
///ATTR SC,RW,VJ
///GROUP1 R1
///GROUP2 S1
///LVARS 0,3,5,0,0,0,0,0
NOP
*_START
JOINT   C00000          0            0              100     +JOINT          EC00000                                     
JOINT   C00001          9            0                  102 +JOINT          EC00001                                     
JOINT   C00002          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00002                                     
JOINT   C00003          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00003                                     
JOINT   C00004          9            0              133     +JOINT          EC00004                                     
JOINT   C00005          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00005                                     
JOINT   C00006          9            0  ARCON   99          162 +JOINT          EC00006                                     
SLENEAR C00007                       0  ARCOF   97          162 +JOINT          EC00007                                     
JOINT   C00008          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00008                                     
JOINT   C00009          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00009                                     
JOINT   C00010          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00010                                     
JOINT   C00011          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00011                                     
JOINT   C00012          9            0                      +JOINT          EC00012                                     
JOINT   C00013          9            0  ARCON   99          162 +JOINT          EC00013                                     
SLENEAR C00014                       0  ARCOF   97  
END
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for Regex. You could make a pattern which searches the text for your starting and ending tags, and then gives you the snippet in-between. [Here's](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/) an article on how to use Regex in VBA.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use loops and a bunch of `Instr` to find the starting and ending characters and then `Mid` to get each line from the text.

Comment: can you provide, or mock up exactly what a typical file would look like?

Comment: Ok, I kind of understand how I can use that as like a search function within the document, I'm unsure how to utilize it to copy over a varying number of lines that match either that patter or to use it to instruct copying what's below it

Comment: Loop through the file and append each line into a single string variable. Use the RegExp Object to extract substrings from the larger text. Use a pattern like `"^C0.*$"` to Regex match with every line starting with "C0". Loop through the collection of Matches and output them to your desired excel range. [Here's](https://software-solutions-online.com/vba-regex-guide/) a second, longer article about Regex in VBA.

Comment: CLR, I edited to include a sample of the backup file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex will definitely give you what you want. If you haven't got the time to learn the dark arts of regex, then with a small compromise (and files consistent with the one you've provided as an example) you could probably get what you want with the following code:

```
Dim myFile As String, textline As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
myFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("c1").Value

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim parser As String, parser_segment As Variant, lookfor As String, outputcolumn As String, col As String

parser = "/Job¦B|C0¦L|//INST¦B|EC0¦S|*_START¦W"

Open myFile For Input As #1
outputcolumn = ""
Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, textline
    
    For Each parser_segment In Split(parser, "|")
        lookfor = Split(parser_segment, "¦")(0)
        col = Split(parser_segment, "¦")(1)
        If UCase(Left(textline, Len(lookfor))) = UCase(lookfor) Then outputcolumn = col
    Next
    If outputcolumn <> "" Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp IO")
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, outputcolumn).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range(outputcolumn & LastRow).Value = textline
        End With
    End If
    
Loop
Close #1
```

The 'secret sauce' is the parser code. This could've been done with a bunch of `If..Then..` statements, but to keep things tidier I went with this. Each segment is made of a search string (which the incoming line must start with) and a column to write to. As each line is ready by your text file reader, it runs it past those segments to see if the `outputcolumn` needs to change. Once it's run through those options, it then finds the next usable cell in the `outputcolumn` and deposits the output there. This continues until it reaches the end of the file.

Hope this gets you some way to your result.

Comment: Thank you! I'm on vacation now, but I'll give it a try when I get back!

Comment: This is a work of art, especially compared to what I was trying to force to work. Thank you!!